# How do I add JSON data to my table, without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

It correctly saves the data to the string, but how do I show the data in my table? Why isn't this code working? Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON("http://wt.ops.few.vu.nl/api/32464776",
function (data) {
var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].category + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].name + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].amount + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].location + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].date + "</td>");
    $('table').append(tr);
}
});
});
```

HTML code: (first entries are just examples, I need the data I added when I click on submit, to show itself)

```
<table id="tabel1" class="sortable">
<caption> <strong>Product Inventory List</strong> </caption>
<tr>
    <th> Name </th> <th> Category </th> <th> Amount </th> <th> Location </th> <th> Purchase Date </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Banana </td> <td> Fruit </td> <td> 1 </td> <td> Amsterdam </td> <td> 2015-11-21 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Shirt </td> <td> Clothes </td> <td> 2 </td> <td> Ijsselstein </td> <td> 2015-09-01 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Laptop </td> <td> Electronics </td> <td> 1 </td> <td> Aalsmeer </td> <td> 2014-12-31 </td>
</tr>
```

And link to the script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"> <script src= adddata.js></script>
```

Comment: `<script src= adddata.js></script>` there are missing double quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add table row in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)

Comment: Check your browser console for errors.

Comment: problem is by importing `jquery` @Nina

Comment: @ Tyr: Thanks, I fixed that. But doesn't affect code.

Comment: @ Raúl Martin: thanks, will check it out

Comment: @ MEAM: like this in the <head>?
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the wrong table: `$('table')` it should be `$('#tabel1')` instead.

Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.getJSON("http://wt.ops.few.vu.nl/api/32464776",
  function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('#tabel1').append("<tr><td>" + data[i].category + "</td></tr>");
    }
  });
});
```

EDIT: Actually, the problem is with this line `$('<tr/>');`, you can see more examples of how you append data to a table here: [Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)